# Multiple URLs in AdSense banner?

Tags: adsense

After visiting Zalando.com and viewing a few products, I am often presented with retargetting Flash ads through Google AdSense showing those very same products. Clicking on one of those products will take me to the Zalando product page *for that product*.

The tracking behind this does not really interest me, but having multiple links in the ad does, as my employer has asked me about creating a banner with 3 similar products or categories so the user can simply click through to the product/category of their choice, rather than a single landing page.

Now, afaict from the [image ads policy](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/bin/answer.py?answer=176108), in particular the section about clicktags and animated image ads, this does not seem to be possible, as it seems this requires changing the destination URL in the clicktag.

Are Zalando (and others) doing something in violation of the policy, both by tracking the user behaviour (and loading external content) as well as by having different URLs or am I missing something?

Can I create the banner my employer asks, without violating AdSense policy?